# fs.symlink can't create directory symlinks on linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, symlink

According to the [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_symlink_target_path_type_callback) creating a symlink that is a `dir` is only available on windows.

This is the command I would use in terminal `ln -r -s ../../../cloud_data/ ./src/data`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var localData = './src/data';
var externalData = '../../cloud_data';

function createSym (){
    fs.symlink(externalData, localData, 'dir', function(d){
        console.info(d);
    });
}

fs.access(localData, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
    if (!err) {
        createSym();
    }else{
        fs.unlink(localData, (err) => {
            if (err) createSym();
        });
    }
});
```

I have written a dirt script for my `pre-build` npm script and it just creates a horrible little icon, but no symlink

[image]

Below you can see that I have created a symlink via namo and alt drag (on the left cloud_data)

[image]

Comment: I would bet you specified the wrong target path. a symlink's path is **relative to the location of the symlink**. I would bet you need to set `externalData` to `../../../cloud_data`

Comment: That's not what the documentation states; it states that the third (`type`) argument is only available on Windows (and ignored for other platforms). And make sure that you're not swapping `target` and `path`.

Comment: @robertklep yeah it means is it a Directory link or Junction link in windows, however Dark Flacon saying the second argument is wrong, not the third,

Comment: @MartinBarker I was commenting on OP, I got the impression that they thought that symlinking _to_ a dir was somehow only supported on Windows :)

Comment: @robertklep I did indeed think that :D To me it looks like symlinking to a folder isn't support in Linux... Which just feels like a straight up lie, so I'm guessing the argument `type` is not supported?

Comment: @DarkFalcon Yes, everything is relative that I am doing. I am actually outputting details in my callbacks. But more to the point, the `data` folder you see wouldn't exist `../../../cloud_data` is what I set it for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last image you can see that the symlink was created just fine. It says "Type: link" and lists a "Link target".

The symlink is "broken" because the target path doesn't exist.

If you have a symlink in

```
/var/wwww/cloud/websites/www/src/data
```

whose target is `../../../cloud_data/`, then that corresponds to

```
/var/wwww/cloud/websites/www/src/../../../cloud_data/
```

which reduces to

```
/var/wwww/cloud/cloud_data/
```

which doesn't exist.

Did you mean `../../../../cloud_data` (or just an absolute path, `/var/wwww/cloud_data`)?

Comment: How interesting, I wonder why `../../../cloud_data` works from command line, but `../../../../cloud_data` works when running it through node?

Comment: @JamieHutber Probably due to the `-r` option to `ln` (which I've never used before). It will work/fail exactly the same way if you use `ln -s ../../../cloud_data/ ./src/data`.

Comment: Interesting, something seems odd to me lol but indeed the adding of a `../` works.  So thank you, I'm afraid this question won#'t help many people either ;)